# Matlab strsplit 3 dots in last string

Tags: matlab, split, serial-port

I'm reading some string data from serial port using MATLAB and splitting each line by commas.  In the last string there is 3 dots appended to the end how to remove them?

```
clear all
clc

teensy=serial('COM4','BaudRate',38400);
fopen(teensy);


for m = 1:10
    line = fscanf(teensy);
    values = strsplit(line,',');
    disp(line);
    disp(values);
end

fclose(teensy);
```

ouput:

```
121.80,0.28,0.28


    '121.80'    '0.28'    '0.28…'

121.72,0.23,0.25


    '121.72'    '0.23'    '0.25…'

122.16,0.25,0.29
```

Comment: You could use multiple delimiters, like `strsplit(line, {',', '...'})` and discard the last empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The ellipses aren't actually there, that's just the way MATLAB displays that there is more content to that cell element.

```
>> {['asdf' char(10)]}

ans = 

    'asdf…'
```

I suspect you have a trailing newline character. strrep(str,char(10),'') will remove newlines. If you have >=16b, you can do erase(str,newline).